# What is the relation between cores and cpu?

Tags: cpu, packages

While running powertop, I got confused with cpu and cores.

If you check the frequency stats image

[image]

It behaves as if each package has multiple cores and each core has multiple CPUs. I could understand multi-cores within a package but unable to understand multi-cpus within each core? Please help me to understand it or provide me with a relevant reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have one package with 2 physical cores, each of which has 2 logical processors. This is probably due to [hyperthreading support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading), though AMD uses a similar system these days, with processor modules. HT makes a single physical core look and act like its 2 logical cores, with some speed-up under multithreaded loads.

Basically, you have a single "chip" or cpu package which contains 2 cores. Each core has some shared elements as well as the elements needed to run 2 threads at once. A 'hyperthreaded' core isn't as fast as 2 non hyperthreaded cores, but with multithreaded applications, is slightly faster than a non hyperthreaded cores.